# AJAX Form - return success/fail message (multiple forms per page)

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using the jquery form plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to show the results of a submitted form on a page.  The issue I'm running into is when there are multiple forms per page and getting the results to show in the div for that specific form.

Here's the form code:

```
<form class="contest-rating-form" id="contest-rating-1" name="Contest" method="post" action="/">    
<input type="hidden" name="rating" value="1">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Vote"></p>
</form>
<div class="message"></div>
```

Note the id="contest-rating-1" - each form on the page has a unique #, so there might be id="contest-rating-55" and id="contest-rating-100", etc.

Here's my JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var options = {
   target: '.message', 
   success: showResponse
  }; 
  $(".contest-rating-form").submit(function() { 
      $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
      return false; 
  }); 
}); 
function showResponse(responseText, statusText)  {}
</script>
```

.message gets updated with a response, but every single instance of .message is updated, not just the one for that form.

Thanks for any help on this!

Edited to add: I could also add the same # to .message, so that .message-1 matches #contest-rating-1, etc. Just not sure how to get that to work in the JS dynamically for each form.

Comment: Well, it pretty much says so, `target=.message`, which means it targets all elements with the class message and puts the response from that particular ajax call in all of them?

Comment: Thanks. I realize that. I'm asking how to get it to show up for only the one that was submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your message element will always be after the form element you could change your code to the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var options = {
   success: showResponse
  }; 
  $(".contest-rating-form").submit(function() { 
      options.target = $(this).next(".message");
      $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
      return false; 
  }); 
}); 
function showResponse(responseText, statusText)  {}
</script>
```

This way `options.target` will always point to the message element below the submitted form.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the page as .php, you can dynamically insert unique class names to the 'message' divs.

Comment: Thanks. I can add unique class names to the message div - I don't know how to call it though in the JS.

Comment: If you add a variable that is a number for eaxh message div, starting with '1' to the end of the div, such as 'message_1', 'message_2', etc, you can then in your JS add a number to 'message'

Comment: Now how would you make that variable the same in JS and PHP, only way I can think of would be to parse your JS file as PHP or some other strange solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but there probably is some reference to `this` in there somewhere, and if the `.message` element is inside `.contest-rating-form` maybe something like this will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".contest-rating-form").submit(function() { 
      $(this).ajaxSubmit({ target: $('.message', this), success: showResponse });
      return false; 
  }); 
}); 
function showResponse(responseText, statusText)  {}
```

It depends on how the plugin is written?

If the the markup is different you will have to climb the DOM to find `.message` with a reference to the `.contest-rating-form`. Try checking the AjaxSubmit site for some clues on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method might help you get your bearings and is always handy when implementing certian types of plugins for multiple instances.

```
/* loop over each form to insulate context in the $.each loop 
   and provide for index avaliablity*/

$(".contest-rating-form").each(function( index ){

        var $form=$(this);                              

        var options={       

            /* can now use indexing if wanted*/
           target: '#message_'+index, 

           /* or traverse within form*/        
           target : $form.find('.message'), 


           success: showResponse
        }; 

      $form.submit(function() { 
          $form.ajaxSubmit(options); 
          return false; 
      }); 

})
```